# Using R for lack-of-fit F-test

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I learnt how to use R to perform an F-test for a lack of fit of a regression model, where $H_0$: "there is no lack of fit in the regression model".

[image: $$F_{LOF} = \frac{MSLF}{MSPE} = \frac{SSLF(\text{model}) / df_1}{SSPE/df_2}$$]

where df_1 is the degrees of freedom for SSLF (lack-of-fit sum of squares) and df_2 is the degrees of freedom for SSPE (sum of squares due to pure error).

In R, the F-test (say for a model with 2 predictors) can be calculated with

`anova(lm(y~x1+x2), lm(y~factor(x1)*factor(x2)))`

Example output:

```
Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
Model 2: y ~ factor(x1) * factor(x2)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     19 18.122                           
2     11 12.456  8    5.6658 0.6254 0.7419
```

F-statistic: 0.6254 with a p-value of 0.7419.

Since the p-value is greater than 0.05, we do not reject $H_0$ that there is no lack of fit. Therefore the model is adequate.

What I want to know is **why use 2 models** and why use the command `factor(x1)*factor(x2)`? Apparently, 12.456 from `Model 2`, is **magically** the SSPE for `Model 1`.

Why?

Comment: If you have a question about statistical tests, you should ask over at [stats.se]; Stack Overflow site is for specific programming questions.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I have been granted permission by @daniel-fischer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140676/using-r-for-lack-of-fit-test) to re-ask, since the original did not gather any answer nor comment.

Comment: the related question is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287532/r-lack-of-fit-test-via-anova)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing whether a model with an interaction improves the model fit.

Model 1 corresponds to an additive effect of `x1` and `x2`.

One way to "check" if the complexity of a model is adequate (in your case whether a multiple regression with additive effects make sense for your data) is to compare the proposed model with a more flexible/complex model.

Your model 2 has the role of this more flexible model. First the predictors are made categorical (by using `factor(x1)` and `factor(x2)`) and then an interaction between them is constructed by `factor(x1)*factor(x2)`. The interaction model includes the additive model as a special case (i.e., model 1 is nested in model 2) and has several extra parameters to provide a potentially better fit to the data.

You can see difference in number of parameters between the two models in the output from `anova`. Model 2 has 8 extra parameters to allow for a better fit but because the p-value is non-significant you would conclude that model 2 (with the extra flexibility based on the additional 8 parameters) actually does not provide a significantly better fit to the data. Thus, the additive model provides a decent enough fit to the data when compared to model 2.

Note that the trick above with making categories (factors) of `x1` and `x2` only really works when number of unique values for `x1` and `x2` is low. If `x1` and `x2` are numeric and each individual has their own value then model 2 is not that useful as you end up with the same number of parameters as you hav observations. In those situations more *ad hoc* modifications such are binning the variables are used.

Comment: WOW!! thank you for answer a question which has eluded math.stackexchange and stats.stackexchange for months!! Is it possible to "figure out" what the 8 extra params that Model 2 has are?

Comment: Yes that is possible but it depends on the data (the number of levels of `x1` and `x2`). Your model 1 has 3 mean parameters (intercept, beta_x1, beta_x2). If you type `summary(model2)` you should see the parameters that are present in that model so you can get a gist from there